# SSIS - Flat File Destination has trailing comma?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-export

I have a simple data flow task. It's a OLE DB Source to Flat File Destination setup.

[image]

One table, one column. Everything works great except there is a trailing comma (column delimiter) in the flat file when I'm done. Why is it putting an extra delimiter after the column as if there were another column?

**Output**

```
dog,
cat,
camel,
moose,
```

How do I get rid of that trailing delimiter?

Comment: Are you sure the row delimiter is not also a comma?

Comment: Good question. I will look. I think you may be right!

Comment: That was it. Thank you!!!!! Make it an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the row delimiter is not also a comma